# Cannot Copy a File Using Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy

I am trying to copy some files using a batch file.

This doesn't work:

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Users\User\Documents\Folder FolderA FolderB\Folder\Folder FolderC FolderD\Folder\Folder" %%f in (*.inc) do copy %%f /R "\\10.1.10.156\c\Folder1\Folder 2\Folder3"
```

This works:

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Users\User\Documents" %%f in (*.inc) do copy %%f "\\10.1.10.156\c\Folder1\Folder 2\Folder3"
```

I also replaced `"C:\Users\User\Documents\Folder FolderA FolderB\Folder\Folder FolderC FolderD\Folder\Folder"` with `%cd%` and I got an error saying `FolderA was unexpected at this time` so I feel like this has to do with the spaces in  the folder named `Folder FolderA FolderB` but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: You could try `do copy "%%f" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a `/R` in your copy statement that shouldn't be there.

Second, as @Dennis van Gils suggests, you need to put quotes around your `%%f` variable in the `copy` statement.  And here's why:

In this command:

```
for /R "C:\a folder with\spaces\" %%f in (*.inc) do copy %%f "\\destination\folder"
```

the variable `%%f` expands to `C:\a folder with\spaces\filename.inc`.  So when `copy` tries to use this it sees:

```
copy C:\a folder
```

--and then it chokes because `C:\a` isn't a valid source and `folder` isn't a valid destination.  So, if you put quotes around the variable like this:

```
rem ---------------------quotes around this variable-----VVVVV
for /R "C:\a folder with\spaces\" %%f in (*.inc) do copy "%%f"  "\\destination\folder"
```

it will expand to:

```
copy "C:\a folder with\spaces\filename.inc" "\\destination\folder"
```

and should work as you expect it to.